# Determining if your text is at the top of the page

Tags: positioning, figure-placement

I have a macro that inserts a wrapped picture into a paragraph - ie, the text wraps around the picture (wrapfig package is used). In order to make it look better, the macro also raises the picture, so that the top of the picture is flush with the top of the first line of the paragraph - the macro uses a negative space command. However, when the paragraph is at the top of the page, that command needs to be skipped. Hence the **question**: is there a simple way to automatically determine whether position of the current text (token) is the top of the page?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Some hints to get you started: Lengths (in TeX points) `\pagegoal` and `\pagetotal` keep a running tally of vertical position. You can `\typeout{\the\pagegoal, \the\pagetotal}` to see where things are. Note that pagegoal initialized with a number larger than the page, and pagetotal may be affected when a paragraph spans pages. This works for single-column layout. Not sure about 2-column, Note that typeout writes to the log, not the PDF.

Comment: I guess I should try something like: \ifdim\pagegoal=\maxdimen ...
\else ... \fi  .  Thanks!